# Казак и запорожец - синонимы. Или нет?

Tags: литература, история

Всегда была уверена, что казаки (украинские) и запорожцы - это синонимы. Но, перечитывая Гоголя, наткнулась на разделение этих слов. Например, в "Пропавшей грамоте" главный герой называется только казаком, а его приятель, которому он помог выпутаться из ведьминской ловушки - только запорожцем. Или в "Ночи перед Рождеством" Чуб - казак, а Пацюк - запорожец. То есть, это разные обозначения? Или всë-таки нет? В общем, запуталась я. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие: вопрос из области общей истории и языковой проблемы не представляет.

Comment: Сами можете ответить на этот вопрос? Если нет, то и не нужно комментировать.

Comment: https://old.bigenc.ru/military_science/text/3866517 - Запорожская Сечь

Comment: Спасибо, но это не объясняет, почему Гоголь разграничивал определения "казак" и "запорожец".

Comment: Потому, что хорошо знал историю родины.

Comment: Потому что Чуб запорожцем не являлся.

Comment: Так хорошо, что писал про огнестрельное оружие и семинарии в 15 веке...